# Postetior from Jeffrey prior of Normal distribtion

Tags: bayesian, inference, prior, posterior, jeffreys-prior

**Context**
I am given a sample from normal distribution $v_i \sim N(\gamma \cdot u_i, \sigma^2)$, $i =1,..., n$.
I need to obtain the posterior distribution using Jeffreys prior for $\gamma$.

**My solution**
I find the Fisher Information as $J = \Bbb E(-(\ell)'')$. If I am not mistaken $$J = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \propto 1$$

This means that the Jeffreys prior is proportional to constant.

As far as I know, posterior is proportional to product of the likelihood function and the Jeffreys prior. Since the Jeffreys prior is constant then the posterior distribution should be **absolutely** the same as the initial distribution that is $ N(\gamma \cdot u_i, \sigma^2)$.

However, most of the posts say that the parameters of the posterior distribution become the averages of parameters from the initial distribution. I studied many posts on stackexchange but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Does [this help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588949/posterior-distribution-for-jeffreys-prior-of-normal-distribution-with-unknown-me) ?

Comment: No, it didn't, I've seen this post. In the second line of the answer, $\bar X$ is used for some reason, instead of $X_i$ as in the prior.

Comment: Yes Jeffreys' prior is constant in this case and the posterior is thus $\propto$ the product of the densities of the observations.

Comment: In the likelihood, a sum appears in the exponent. To get rid of it we multiply and divide by $n$. So, the posterior will be $N(\sum v_i /n, \sigma^2 /n)$. Am I right?